# Chromebook fails to load Kubuntu installer USB

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, kubuntu, chrome-book

I'm trying to install Kubuntu on my Chromebook (HP Chromebook 11 G3). I got the installer from the Kubuntu website (the amd64 one, as running uname -m gives me x86_64), checked all of the checksums, and dd'ed it onto a 32gb flash drive. It is in my left-most USB port (which is USB 2 as i dont have USB 3 ports). The drive itself is USB 3. When I run Ctrl-U, which should boot, the screen goes flashes dark, beeps loudly, and goes back to the 'OS Verification is off' section. How do I get it to boot?

Comment: According to https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/debug_buttons.md you need to have run `crossystem dev_boot_usb=1` first, and that may require you to get into developer mode first.

Comment: Did both of those... @icarus